# Profile user php

Tags: php, profile

I'm trying to build a page for user profiles, but I'm having difficulties.
I do not want to create the profile  for the user just logged, but permanent user profiles, where you can then watch them all.

type: profile.php? id = 1

I'm using UserPie, which can be found on github.

Actually my profile.php page is this:

```
<?php require_once("models/config.php"); 

$id = $_GET['id']);

if (empty($_GET['id'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $rws["username"]; ?> - <?php echo $websiteName; ?></title>
<?php require_once("head_inc.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php require_once("navbar.php"); ?>

<?php if (is_null($sql)): ?>
<h3 class="page-header">ERROR</h3>
User not found!
<?php else: ?>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>ID: <?php echo $rws['user_id']; ?></p>       
<p>Welcome to your account page <strong><?php echo $rws['username']; ?></strong></p>
<p>You joined on <?php echo date("l \\t\h\e jS Y", $rws['sign_up_date']); ?> </p>       
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I cannot make it work.
Do you have any suggestion?

---

I solved in this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack. in your code "if (is_null($sql)):" is definitley wrong. But back to your question which is not really clear. To store the data permanently you can store them into data bases.

Comment: what error you get..??

Comment: @bub How come `if(is_null($sql)):` could be wrong?

Comment: @Marco `$id = $_GET['id']);` there is a syntax error. it will be `$id = $_GET['id'];` Do you have any error?? then it will be easy for some one to give solution.

Comment: @D4V1D $sql is a string, isn't it? and here you always go through this line, so that $sql contains the  string, otherwise with an empty $_GET['id'] it will stop beacause of the die()

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I corrected the syntax of GET, but at the time the error is this: [27-Mar-2015 10:55:39 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli_query () Expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object Given in /home/marcobon/public_html/user/profile.php on line 11
[27-Mar-2015 10:55:39 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli_error () Expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object Given in /home/marcobon/public_html/user/profile.php on line 11

Comment: Perhaps accidentally connect to the database?

Comment: Where are you getting the `$db` parameter? It should include a mysqli connection, but it doesn't. And why you are selecting from the DB where user id is not the user's id? Replace the `!=` with `=`

Comment: I followed some examples of the other pages, if you check the script I'm using: https://github.com/booruguru/UserPie you can understand better. How can I fix? PS: Tried, but blank page.

Comment: Seems like that UserPie doesn't use prepared statements in the queries, I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Since you are expect only 1 response, you can just get the 1 result and not loop through them. `$result` is false on query failure. The result is a `MysqliResult` object, which has the `num_rows` member variable which states the number of results.

```
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    // Output template/html here
} else {
    // ERROR could not find
}
```

Additionally `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != '$id'";` is exploitable with SQL Injection. To avoid this use the prepared statements in `mysqli` [Prepared Statements - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. This script is so unsafe? I saw the config.php file in a string that does so:  //Construct a db instance
 $db = new $sql_db();
 if(is_array($db->sql_connect(
       $db_host, 
       $db_user,
       $db_pass,
       $db_name, 
       $db_port,
       false, 
       false
 ))) {
  die("Unable to connect to the database");
 }

Comment: is not ok? if you can, I ask you to take a look at the package UserPie and if you can, let me know if it is unsafe and outdated. Thank you very much